# Syntax reference for change_detected<= (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1'); in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl

```
SIGNAL change_detected : boolean;
VARIABLE temp : std_logic_vector(2 DOWNTO 0);
```

It is used in combination with a shifter. It looks like a compare statement, it might show a 1 in "change_detected" when the previous value "temp(2)" is zero and the current value "temp(1)" is one, but this code does not use the if else structure. Does anyone have a reference on the syntax and why this works?

What is the syntax reference for `change_detected<= (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1');` in VHDL?

Most VHDL references I see, show compare statements a form that looks like:

```
change_detected<= true when (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1') else false;
```

or

```
 if(temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1') then
change_detected<= true;
else
change_detected<= false;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(temp(2) = '0') and (temp(1) = '1')` (it's not a statement) has type `boolean` and can be used anywhere that a boolean expression is needed.  A controlling expression for `when` or `if` should be `boolean`, and so should the value written to a signal of type `boolean`.

The total

```
change_detected <= (temp(2) = '0') and (temp(1) = '1');
```

is a signal assignment statement.

The alternatives you show are not actually correct for the declarations you give, because they both attempt to assign a value of type `STD_LOGIC` into a signal of type `boolean`.

Another notable difference is that signal assignment of the boolean expression will assign `change_detected` to either `true` or `false`, while the `when` and `if` forms will either assign `1` or leave the value unchanged.  In that regard, the equivalent `STD_LOGIC` assignment would be:

```
change_detected <= '1' when (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1') else '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

> For declarations:
>
> ```
> SIGNAL change_detected : boolean;
> VARIABLE temp : std_logic_vector(2 DOWNTO 0);
> ```
>
> What is the VHDL syntax reference for:
>
> ```
> change_detected <= (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1');
> ```
>
> Found used in combination with a shifter. It looks like a compare
>   statement, and would show `change_detected` TRUE when `temp(2)` is '0'
>   and `temp(1)` is '1', but this code does not use the if else
>   structure.
>
> Does anyone have a reference on the syntax and why this works?

This is a simple signal assignment statement (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 10.5.2  Simple signal assignments) with a waveform supplied by a logical expression (9. Expressions, 9.1 General) of the form *relation* **AND** *relation*.

The two relations are of the form shift_expression relational_operator shift_expression, where both shift expressions are simple expressions and the relational operator is "=" (equality), which returns a BOOLEAN.

There is an AND operator declared for type BOOLEAN that returns a type BOOLEAN which is either TRUE when both relations evaluate TRUE or is FALSE when either relation evaluates FALSE. (Basic Boolean algebra).

> Most VHDL references I see, show compare statements a form that looks
>   like:
>
> ```
> change_detected <= true when (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1') else
>                    false;
> ```

This is the form of a conditional signal assignment statement which in the 2008 revision of VHDL can be a concurrent statement. It is described in 10.5.3 Conditional signal assignments, which shows that it has an if statement (10.8 If statement) equivalent which you show as the alternative:

> or
>
> ```
> if (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1') then
>     change_detected <= true;
> else
>     change_detected <= false;
> end if;
> ```

These examples are equivalent to the above simple signal assignment statement.

Also note that for `(temp(2) ='0')` and `(temp(1) ='1')` the outer parentheses of each expression are superfluous.

Comment: If they are equivalent, I still don't get why I get illegal sequential statement error for change_detected <= true when (temp(2) ='0') and (temp(1) ='1') else
                   false; when it is used in a PROCESS.

Comment: A conditional signal assignment statement is not supported as a sequential statement (inside a process or a subprogram) before IEEE Std 1076-2008. Either your VHDL tool(s) aren't -2008 compliant or you're missing a setting or command line switch to operate with -2008 compatible syntax. This wasn't part of your question.